# creating dataframe column name tag with pasted string in R

Tags: r, dataframe, paste

This works

```
> data.frame('a50'=c(1,2,3))
  a50
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

This give me "a50"

```
> h=50
> paste('a',h,sep='')
[1] "a50"
```

So why doesn't this work

```
> data.frame((paste('a',50,sep=''))=c(1,2,3))
Error: unexpected '=' in "data.frame((paste('a',50,sep=''))="
```

What I want is to create a dataframe with column names that tells me the current h in each loop of h.

Comment: `setNames(data.frame(c(1,2,3)), paste0('a',h))`

Comment: cheers it works! but do you know why the code I wrote didn't?

Comment: It is because of how the functions are evaluated. Search for non-standard evaluation . This link can be a good starting point https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html